# Convert jpg to webp using imagewebp

Tags: php, webp

I'm having trouble using imagewebp to convert an image to webp.

I use this code:

```
$filename = dirname(__FILE__) .'/example.jpg';

$im = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);

$webp =imagewebp($im, str_replace('jpg', 'webp', $filename));
imagedestroy($im);

var_dump($webp);
```

$webp returns true but when I try to view the webp-image in Chrome it just shows blank, but with the correct size. If I instead load the image and set headers with PHP (see below) it shows up, but with wrong colors (too much yellow).

```
$im = imagecreatefromwebp('example.webp');
header('Content-Type: image/webp');
imagewebp($im);
imagedestroy($im);
```

If I convert the same image with command line it works as expected.

```
cwebp -q 100 example.jpg -o example.webp
```

I'm testing this on Ubuntu 14, Apache 2.4.7 and PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.4.

Comment: Hmm.. ok. It doesn't explain my problem with white jpeg -> webp though :(.

Comment: I've been trying this out some more and images up to 1920x1440 seem to work just fine. Larger images loads, shows up for a split second and then just goes blank. The image size is correct though. My current memory limit is 128M, but it doesn't help when I set it to 256M either.

Comment: @StefanEdberg: I am converting from webp tp jpg.After conversion even I am facing too much yellow in the picture.How can I avoid that.Pls help ..

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've got the same problem.

Comment: No, I haven't looked at it anything since I wrote this question. Sorry.

Comment: I have now reported it as a bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70045

Comment: Seems like it has been/will be fixed: 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66590
https://github.com/libgd/libgd/issues/176

Comment: Works for me with 5.6.4-4ubuntu6.3.

Comment: Works for me on PHP 5.6.33-0+deb8u1 (and above, I would guess)

Answer (score 11):

I user this

```
function webpConvert2($file, $compression_quality = 80)
{
    // check if file exists
    if (!file_exists($file)) {
        return false;
    }
    $file_type = exif_imagetype($file);
    //https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php
    //exif_imagetype($file);
    // 1    IMAGETYPE_GIF
    // 2    IMAGETYPE_JPEG
    // 3    IMAGETYPE_PNG
    // 6    IMAGETYPE_BMP
    // 15   IMAGETYPE_WBMP
    // 16   IMAGETYPE_XBM
    $output_file =  $file . '.webp';
    if (file_exists($output_file)) {
        return $output_file;
    }
    if (function_exists('imagewebp')) {
        switch ($file_type) {
            case '1': //IMAGETYPE_GIF
                $image = imagecreatefromgif($file);
                break;
            case '2': //IMAGETYPE_JPEG
                $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
                break;
            case '3': //IMAGETYPE_PNG
                    $image = imagecreatefrompng($file);
                    imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
                    imagealphablending($image, true);
                    imagesavealpha($image, true);
                    break;
            case '6': // IMAGETYPE_BMP
                $image = imagecreatefrombmp($file);
                break;
            case '15': //IMAGETYPE_Webp
               return false;
                break;
            case '16': //IMAGETYPE_XBM
                $image = imagecreatefromxbm($file);
                break;
            default:
                return false;
        }
        // Save the image
        $result = imagewebp($image, $output_file, $compression_quality);
        if (false === $result) {
            return false;
        }
        // Free up memory
        imagedestroy($image);
        return $output_file;
    } elseif (class_exists('Imagick')) {
        $image = new Imagick();
        $image->readImage($file);
        if ($file_type === "3") {
            $image->setImageFormat('webp');
            $image->setImageCompressionQuality($compression_quality);
            $image->setOption('webp:lossless', 'true');
        }
        $image->writeImage($output_file);
        return $output_file;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

It works:

```
$jpg=imagecreatefromjpeg('filename.jpg');
$w=imagesx($jpg);
$h=imagesy($jpg);
$webp=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
imagecopy($webp,$jpg,0,0,0,0,$w,$h);
imagewebp($webp, 'filename.webp', 80);
imagedestroy($jpg);
imagedestroy($webp);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Comment: This is faster than ob_get_contents() method by about 10%, and output is smaller as quality is set to 80 .

Answer (score 7):

I had same problem, my solution is:

```
$file='hnbrnocz.jpg';
$image=  imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
ob_start();
imagejpeg($image,NULL,100);
$cont=  ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
imagedestroy($image);
$content =  imagecreatefromstring($cont);
imagewebp($content,'images/hnbrnocz.webp');
imagedestroy($content);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work for me when I test with one of the images that I submitted with the bug.

Answer (score 2):

### Converting JPG to WEBP is as simple as that

```php
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg('example.jpg');
imagewebp($image, 'example.webp');
imagedestroy($image);
```

This creates an "example.webp" file from an "example.jpg". Provided you have the [`gd` extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) added in your `composer.json` as such: `"ext-gd": "*"`. You can [delete the JPG file](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_unlink.asp) after.

> There's nothing wrong with the code in the question - the OP encountered a **bug**, which he [reported](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70045) and [got taken care of](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66590) **in PHP 5.6.11. Later versions have this bug fixed.**

---

### Converting images (various formats) to WEBP

This function converts files of common image formats (`PNG`, `JPG/JPEG`, `GIF`, `WEBP`) to `WEBP`.

The [Type declarations](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php) require at least PHP 7.1.0. Remove them if your version is prior.

```php
/**
 * @param string $inputFile: relative or absolute path
 * @param string $outputFile: relative or absolute path
 * @param int $quality of output: 0 is worst, 100 is best
 * @return void
 */
function convertImageToWebp(string $inputFile, string $outputFile, int $quality = 100): void
{
    $fileType = exif_imagetype($inputFile);

    switch ($fileType) {
        case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($inputFile);
            imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
            imagealphablending($image, true);
            imagesavealpha($image, true);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($inputFile);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($inputFile);
            imagepalettetotruecolor($image);
            imagealphablending($image, true);
            imagesavealpha($image, true);
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_WEBP:
            rename($inputFile, $outputFile);
            return;
        default:
            return;
    }

    imagewebp($image, $outputFile, $quality);

    imagedestroy($image);
}
```

##### Usage examples:

```php
convertImageToWebp('image.png', 'image.webp');
convertImageToWebp('/var/www/app/assets/image.jpg', '/var/www/app/assets/image.webp');
convertImageToWebp('/home/paul/image.gif', 'image.webp', 90);
```

Both relative and absolute paths are fine. The 3rd quality param is optional - I've set a default.

##### Requirements: (add in `composer.json` under `require`)

```json
"ext-exif": "*",
"ext-gd": "*"
```

The [`exif` extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.exif.php) is needed for the `exif_imagetype` function.
The [`gd` extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php) is there for the other ones: `imagecreatefromxyz`, `imagewebp`, `imagedestroy`.

##### Explanation:

- the [`exif_imagetype` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php) reads the file type from the image's metadata
- if the `$inputFile` is

  - a `WEBP` already: it is just moved to the `$outputFile` location
  - a `PNG`/`JPG/JPEG` or `GIF`: the image is

    1. loaded via [imagecreatefromxyz](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php),
    2. converted and written to the `$outputFile` with the [imagewebp function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php) (yes, **it both converts and writes**) and
    3. finally destroyed by [imagedestroy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagedestroy.php) (the image object, to free up memory)
  - something else: just exit
- if the `$outputFile` already exists, it will be overwritten (both `rename` and `imagewebp` functions do so)
- the 3 extra lines for the `GIF` and the `PNG` are required because of their special characteristics (color representation, transparency)